# How to use Freetype in win32 apps

Tags: freetype2

Does any one know samples/tutorials of how to use Freetype in win32 apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official freetype2 tutorial is [here](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html).

UPDATE

Answering the question on how to display bitmap on Win32, here are few links: [1](http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson13.htm), [2](http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_MFC_Example/Load-Draw-Bitmap-File-CBitmap-BITMAPINFOHEADER.htm), [3](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/bitmaps.html)

Comment: I am looking for something that is specifically used with win32.

Comment: Why? It's crossplatform. On one of the recent projects I was using SDL + SDL_ttf (freetype2 add-on). IMO, you can adapt it to whatever you need.

Comment: You are correct. The only place i am struggling is to try to write the bitmap into the screen. I am not able to paint the bitmap buffer. Do you know any source where i can get this info? google is not helping here ..